# Post-receive hook not firing

Tags: git, hook

I installed "[Dazzle](https://github.com/hbons/Dazzle)", recommended by sparkleshare. Sparkleshare syncs and everything is working fine.

I would like to add a hook to my git repository.

/home/storage/TEST/
               - branches
               - hooks
               - info
               - objects
               ...

My hook is /home/storage/TEST/hooks/post-receive

This is my hook (it's just a test):

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /home/test.txt
```

I did `chmod -x /home/storage/TEST/hooks/post-receive`

But when Sparkleshare syncs, the hook doesn't run.

Comment: did you mean: ``chmod +x``?

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't using the `.git` directory structure?

Comment: Dazzle installs the directory storage and creates this directory structure..

Everything works fine except the hooks and there is no .git directory.

Yes i meant chmod +x :)

Comment: Now I wonder, is sparkleshare *pushing* to or *pulling* from the repository where you placed the hook?

Comment: Both, SparkleShare is a dropbox alternative (syncing both ways).

Comment: The directory structure is this way because the git repository was create with this command "git init --bare /home/storage/TEST/"

I'ts a bare repository, but it still doesn't explain why the post-receive hook isn't fired

Comment: Try a `chmod 775` to be sure